# Sulu smart field type sorting order?

Tags: sorting, sulu

I'm using smart content for displaying custom article type (news). At documentation:

https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.2/reference/content-types/smart_content.html#

it says *"Depending on the DataProvider you can define where the items come from (Datasource), what tags the filtered items must have, **how they are sorted**, and how many results you want to get."* but then not a word about how to define sorting?

Data provider is article bundle:
https://github.com/sulu/SuluArticleBundle/blob/2.x/Resources/doc/content-types.md

but again, not a word about how to set order field and order direction.

I want to sort them by creation date, newer to older, probably most common sort direction. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the `Blog` page in the sulu demo administration interface (https://sulu.rocks/admin), there is a smart content called `Articles`. If you open the configuration overlay for that smart content, some filters appear, one of those is `Sort by`, another one `Sort direction`. You can sort the results of the smart content using those filters.

Comment: Thank you. I would never assume that. Not in a million years. :) Expected it to be somewhere in the code, some parameter.